# Query String is not added while navigating in lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightningnavigation

[image]
Hi All, I'm trying to navigating to place order page from order details page but the query string is not displayed in the URL section.I'm getting the URL like below:

> https://sf.force.com/lightning/cmp/lightningdeve__CreateContactOrder

But here the query string is  not added I need like below

> https://sf.force.com/lightning/cmp/lightningdeve__CreateContactOrder?myAttr=attrValue

Any ideas where did I made a mistake

### My component

```html
<aura:component>   
    <!-- attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="contactId" type="String"/>
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>

    <div class="slds-p-around_small">
        <lightning:recordForm
            recordId="{!v.contactId}"
            objectApiName="Contact"
            layoutType="Full"
            columns="1"
            mode="readonly" />
     </div>
     <div class="slds-p-around_small">
        <lightning:button name="Order Now" label="Order Now" onclick="{!c.doOrder}" variant="brand"/>
     </div>
</aura:component>
```

### controller :

```js
({
    doOrder : function(component, event, helper) {
        var pageReference = component.find("navService");
        var pageReferenceNav = {
            "type": "standard__component",
            "attributes": {
                "componentName" : "lightningdeve__CreateContactOrder"              
            },
            "state": {
                // "contactId" : component.get('v.contactId') 
                "myAttr" : "attrValue"
            }
        };
        pageReference.navigate(pageReferenceNav);
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Query parameters are only included in URLs as long as they have a namespace prefix of some kind (e.g. "c__"). See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_add_params_url) for further details.